# "shortcut" same type as MY COMPUTER where is it located?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, windows-registry, desktop

Shortcuts such as `My Computer` or `Outlook` are generated by the system automatically.  When we right-click on it and go properties, it usually opens a `.cpl` file(control panel extension)

When you open the `Desktop` folder, you will see shortcuts like these usually have a name and `SYSTEM FOLDER` underneath the name.

My question is, where are those system generated shortcuts located? How would we manually create another sone?

(Windows XP environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of shortcuts (Namespace shortcuts) can be created using explorer.exe command line parameters:
***EXPLORER.EXE [/n] [/e] [,/root,{object}] [[,/select],{sub object}]***

**/n** - Opens a new "My Computer" view of the object, even if already open.

**/e** - Opens an "Explorer" view of the object.

**/root,{object}** - The specified root for the display. Explorer.exe /e,/root,D:\ will open an "Explorer" view of the D: drive.

**/select,{sub object}** - The specified folder or file receives focus. Explorer.exe /select,C:\WinNT\System32\Regedt32.exe will open a window view of C:\WinNT\System32 and the NT Registry Editor will receive focus. To do the same with an "Explorer" view, Explorer.exe /e,/select,C:\WinNT\System32\Regedt32.exe

For creating shortcut to "My computer" use *Explorer /E,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}* as shortcut target.

Some other "standard" Namespaces CLSID (you can find even more in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID):

- My documents: *Explorer /N,::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}*
- Control Panel: *Explorer /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}*
- Printers and faxes: *Explorer /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}*
- Scanners and cameras: *Explorer /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}::{E211B736-43FD-11D1-9EFB-0000F8757FCD}*
- Administration tools: *Explorer /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}::{D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153}*
- Task Scheduler: *Explorer /N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}::{D6277990-4C6A-11CF-8D87-00AA0060F5BF}*
- Recycle Bin: *Explorer /N,::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
- Default Web browser: Explorer /N,::{871C5380-42A0-1069-A2EA-08002B30309D}*

So for creating your own shortcuts if such type **theoreticaly** you should create/register your custom CLSID. It's from area of programming (COM related) and i'm not 100% sure about it...

Comment: this is great info, thank you, i just have one more question, shortcuts like this where are they stored? I mean physical path in a folder

Comment: The shortcut is stored as a .lnk file in the directory where they appear.  So if you create one in your Desktop, it's in the Desktop folder.  If you create one in C:\Folder, it's in C:\Folder.

Comment: you are talking bout regular shortcut, i was referring to special shortcut that's generated automatically by system. if you go to desktop folder and type dir, you dont see any .lnk file for My Computer

Comment: System shortcuts (like 'My computer") are predefined and preconfigured in windows registry (as 'build-in' shell feature). 
But if you will create custom shortcuts according to scheme specified above - it will appears as regular .lnk shortcuts (but with additional features like properties and so on).